# Calling API inside foreach loop in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dotnet-httpclient

I have the following function that call my API:

```
private async void applyMe(int id, string data)
{
   string url = $"https://localhost:44382/api/isc/getdata?id=" + id + "&data=" + data;
   ApiHelper.InitializeClient();
   string _apiResult = await APIProcessor.LoadApi(url);     
}
```

API Helper

```
public static class ApiHelper
{
    public static HttpClient ApiClient { get; set; }
    public static void InitializeClient() 
    {
        ApiClient = new HttpClient();
        ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/jason"));
    }
}
```

APIProcessor

```
public class APIProcessor
{
    public static async Task<string> LoadApi(string url)
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await ApiHelper.ApiClient.GetAsync(url))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string _apiResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return _apiResult;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to call my API inside `foreach` loop as below

```
using (myEntities _context = new myEntities ())
{
    foreach (var item in _context.items.Where(s => s.id >= 1 && s.id <= 500))
      {
          applyMe(item.id, item.data);
      }
 }
```

The API not calling yet because of `async await` :(
Please how can I solve this issue?

Comment: `await getData(...`?

Comment: @Charlieface Forget the name of  API, I changed it

Comment: OK `await applyMe(...` the name of the function wasn't my point obviously. You need to `await` an async function

Comment: @Charlieface How?

Comment: It's `async Task` all the way up, until you get to the UI event handler, then use `async void`. So declare `private async Task applyMe(...`

Comment: Regarding the `async void` methods in general, take a look at this: [Avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void). Also you could consider adding the `Async` suffix to your asynchronous methods, to comply with the [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types).

Answer (score 2):

Use Task.WhenAll(). It returns an awaitable that will get completed when all other tasks are finished. In the end you need to wait without blocking the thread. see [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__)

```
using (myEntities _context = new myEntities ())
{
    await Task.WhenAll(_context.items
                               .Where(s => s.id >= 1 && s.id <= 500)
                               .Select(s => applyMe(item.id, item.data))
                      );
}
```

**Important!** The applyMe should return a Task and not remain void. The async void pattern is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `IAsyncEnumerable<MyModel>` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8))

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<MyModel> GetItems()
{
    IQueryable<T> query = this._context.items;

    query = query.Where(s => s.id >= 1 && s.id <= 500);

    return query.AsAsyncEnumerable();
}
```

And use it with:

```
IAsyncEnumerable<MyModel>> items = GetItems();
await foreach (var myModel in items)
{
    //Call external api         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two small adjustments to make this work:
First Task iso void

```
private async Task getData(int id, string data)
{
    string url = $"https://localhost:44382/api/isc/getdata?id=" + id + "&data=" + data;
    ApiHelper.InitializeClient();
    string _apiResult = await APIProcessor.LoadApi(url);     
}
```

and second, await the getData call

```
using (myEntities _context = new myEntities ())
{
    foreach (var item in _context.items.Where(s => s.id >= 1 && s.id <= 500))
      {
          await getData(item.id, item.data);
      }
 }
```